# How to make div disappear after clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Like in the topic. After clicking empty gear (norm) I want to make it change to filled (hov) and show up div (show), but it doesn't work.

Before using ifs everything was working, so there must be something wrong with them.

js:

```
function list() {

  if (document.getElementById('hov').style.display === 'none') {
    document.getElementById('norm').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('hov').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'grid';      
  }

  if (document.getElementById('hov').style.display === 'flex') {  
    document.getElementById('norm').style.display = 'flex';
    document.getElementById('hov').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('show').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

html:

```
 <button class="men" onclick="list()"><img id="norm" src="img/gearw.png" height="28px"><img id="hov" src="img/gearwhover.png" height="28px"></button>
```

Comment: Do you get any error message? Can you also show some html code?

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You should probably have an `else if` for that second condition, or a `return` in the first one. Or else you're running the `display` change (to not `none`), then the second condition also becomes true, and reverts to `display: none`. Might not be your issue, but maybe it'll help…

Comment: Did you add a click event listener to "norm"?

Comment: There is my html code:  <button class="men" onclick="list()"> <img id="norm" src="img/gearw.png" height="28px"> <img id="hov" src="img/gearwhover.png" height="28px">  </button> . I tried adding else if or adding onclick to imgs, but it didn't help :/

Comment: Alright, i have found a solution by my own. If display is set to none and you want to check it then you have to use it: var div = document.getElementById('hov');
    
    if (window.getComputedStyle(div).display === 'none'){

Comment: Great add it in the answer it would help people

Comment: `element.style.display` refers to **inline styles only**.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a bit of a misunderstanding of what `display` does (you can read up on it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). Setting it to `none` won't make it invisible. Instead, you could use `visibility`.

For example:

```js
function list() {
    var norm = document.getElementById("norm");
    var hov  = document.getElementById("hov");
    
    if (hov.style.visibility === "hidden") {
        norm.style.visibility = "hidden";
        hov .style.visibility = "visible";
    
    } else if (hov.style.visibility === "visible") {
        norm.style.visibility = "visible";
        hov .style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

```html
<button class = "men" onclick = "list()">
    <img id = "norm" src = "img/gearw.png"      height = "28px">
    <img id = "hov"  src = "img/gearwhover.png" height = "28px" style = "visibility: hidden">
</button>
```

Other than that, your code seems very weird (your JS talks about a "show" element that's not in your HTML document?), and its not quite clear from the question what you're trying to accomplish. There probably is a much more elegant way to do what you want, but without telling us, we can't know.

If I were to guess, I'd say that you were trying to make the image on the button change when the user hovers over it, in which case you'd probably be better off using CSS for that, but again I can't know for sure.

Anyways, I wish you the best of luck in your project!

Answer (score -1):

Did you write link to JQuery?

write `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` into the end of the `body`, but before `body`. If it doesn't work, sorry( I can't give another advice